# HTTP redirect with header function does not work

Tags: php, http-headers

`header("Location: …" );` does not seem to be working:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){ 
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    Admin Panel
    </title>
</head>
<body>

 </body
</html>
<?php
} else {
    header("Location: http://echo2.site40.net/cms/admin/login.php" );
 }
?>
```

Comment: Can you define _not working_? Do you have any error?

Comment: no just will not go to the login page and it must becuae session is not set

Comment: Well, `$_SESSION['user']` might be undefined...

Comment: In my server you code seems to work fine. Try to negate it with `if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))` to see if it works, or see if the Session variable is set. `echo $_SESSION['user']` and see what it prints .

Comment: test page: (http://echo2.site40.net/cms/admin/) not working | test page 2 (http://br-de.tk/css working)

Comment: Reverse the order of execution. You can't output anything to the browser before issuing headers, otherwise the won't work. Use `if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) : header("Location:...") else : //start outputting stuff endif; `

Comment: thanks for the help but it turns of that it was the server not the code

Comment: @user1523770 glad you've solved the current issue, but you shouldn't output anything before issuing headers. Keep that in mind for the future, it will prevent headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working if I exactly copy paste the code...

Still look for the empty white-spaces before start of the `<?php`